# Windows Phone 8 - media.Play() gets UnauthorizedAccessException on locked screen

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to write my very first Windows phone application and I am stuck on something. I have never had hands on experience with C# before.

The app is a simple count down timer that plays a sound at the end.

This is a Windows Phone 8 app. I created it using Visual Studio 2015 using: new Project > Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Windows 8 > Windows Phone > Blank App

I added a Background Task with Audio in Declarations in the Package.appxmanifest

I am using a MediaElement in the MainPage.xaml

```
<MediaElement Name="media" 
              AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" 
              Source="Audio/bell.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />
```

I added Audio/bell.mp3 to the project.

I am using a DispatchTimer like this

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(timer_Tick);


void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (tik > 0)
                tik--;

            progress.Value = progress.Maximum - tik;

            if(tik <= 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                media.Play();
            }
        }
```

It works perfectly fine with the screen is unlocked, the sounds plays at the end of the time.

However, if I lock the screen before the time is up, the timer continues (and that's perfect), but when the time is up, I get **System.UnauthorizedAccessException** on media.Play();

```
Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I don't understand why I get access denied on locked screen only. What do I need to do to change that? I would really like the sound to play in locked screen to notify the user that the time is up.

I tried enabling the app to run in locked screen adding

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

to App.xaml.cs but I get

```
The name PhoneApplicationService does not exist in this context
```

and I can't add the Microsoft.Phone.dll otherwise I can't deploy the app onto the phone...

Comment: Windows Phone has tight restrictions on what apps do. I suppose this is to stop "annoying" apps that do things like playing sounds on random occasions :) To play a sound on a locked screen, you need to schedule an Alarm/Reminder. This is what apps like powernAPP or Avirall do (these are popular timer apps)

Comment: @NothingsImpossible Thanks for the suggestion. Apparently alarms/reminders are not available for Windows Phne 8.1 WinRT apps, only for Silverlight apps. That's also why I couldn't add Microsoft.Phone.dll. Ideally I'd like to avoid using Silverlight, so I wonder if there's an alternative that works in my case.